# Openstack services gets in hook-failed issues when deployed using JUJU

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I deployed Openstack successfully using Juju Charm over MaaS servers. Openstack is up and running but after sometime some of the Units lands up into error/blocked state(i.e charm hook issues regarding to update-status and config-changed) but after doing workarounds(juju resolved & debug-hooks) it does work.

Is there any thing that i missed out because of which i come across of this charm hook issues frequently..?